# Is using mutexes over CS harmful for the system?

Tags: windows, synchronization, mutex

I came across few articles talking about differences between Mutexes and Critical sections.
One of the major differences which I came across is , Mutexes run in kernel mode whereas Critical sections mainly run in user mode.

So if this is the case then arent the applications which use mutexes harmful for the system in case the application crashes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Win32 Mutexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handles when you need to have a lock or synchronization across threads in **different** processes.

Use [Win32 CRITICAL_SECTIONs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you need to have a lock between threads within the **same** process. It's cheaper as far as time and doesn't involve a kernel system call unless there is lock contention. Critical Section objects in Win32 can't span process boundaries anyway.

"Harmful" is the wrong word to use.  More like "Win32 mutexes are slightly more expensive that Win32 Critical Sections in terms of performance".  A running app that uses mutexes instead of critical sections won't likely hurt system performance. It will just run minutely slower. But depending on how often your lock is acquired and released, the difference may not even be measurable.

I forget the perf metrics I did a long time ago. The bottom line is that EnterCriticalSection and LeaveCriticalSection APIs are on the order of 10-100x faster than the equivalent usage of WaitForSingleObject and ReleaseMutex.  (on the order of 1 microsecond vs 1 millisecond).